# Adding Character to the end of the BufferedInputStream java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, bufferedinputstream

I'm getting inputstream from MimeMessage. In the InputStream, at the end I want to add \r\n.\r\n

To represent the end of the message.

Please suggest.

Comment: Just add it, what's the problem ?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat How to add? Please explain using java code.

Comment: You need to add it when the text is generated.  Another option is to write a chaining stream but that is much harder.

Comment: **Why** are you trying to do this?  The POP3 and SMTP protocols do something similar, but note that they also need to handle lines in the message that contain just ".".  Does your use case require you to handle that?  You might want to look at [JavaMail's SMTPOutputStream](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPOutputStream.java?rev=680).  Also, if you're using the getInputStream method, note that you're not getting the headers for the message.  If you want the headers, you need to use the writeTo method.

Comment: @BillShannon As mentioned in my previous post, I'm trying to get ride of Javamail to send mail when smtp server is hosted in local.

Comment: I still think you're wasting your time trying to optimize something that's not going to matter, but if you're determined to do it then you're going to need something like SMTPOutputStream.  For that matter, you might want to look at all the JavaMail SMTP provider source code and figure out how to start with that to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append it on the fly with

```
public class ConcatInputStream extends InputStream {
    private final InputStream[] is;
    private int last = 0;

    ConcatInputStream(InputStream[] is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    public static InputStream of(InputStream... is) {
        return new ConcatInputStream(is);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        for (; last < is.length; last++) {
            int read = is[last].read(b, off, len);
            if (read >= 0)
                return read;
        }
        throw new EOFException();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        for (; last < is.length; last++) {
            int read = is[last].read();
            if (read >= 0)
                return read;
        }
        throw new EOFException();
    }

    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        long available = 0;
        for(int i = last; i < is.length; i++)
            available += is[i].available();
        return (int) Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, available);
   }
}
```

In your case you can do

```
InputStream in = 
InputStream in2 = ConcatInputStream.of(in, 
                              new ByteArrayInputStream("\r\n.\r\n".getBytes()));
```

Comment: I'd use a while loop or something, that return before increment is a bit too sneaky for my liking :)

Comment: @md_5 imagine you are sending a large email from a file.  This solution allows you read chunks of a few KB at a time and finally send the `.` at the end.  If you read all the data in first, you need to use at least 1-2x the size of the file which might not be ideal. ;)

Comment: @md_5 BTW which part of Melbourne are you from?  I grew up in Eltham North.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  The return inputstream is not marksupported. Before Concat first inputstream is marksupported. How to make concated inputstream as mark supported.

Comment: @Roshan you need to override mark(), markSupported() and reset();

Comment: @Roshan it is hard to write a generic solution. As people will copy the code and use it, it has be generic.  For your use case it is relatively trivial. You can pass those methods to the first InputStream,

Answer (score 1):

Just store the InputStraem value in a String, then add it to that String:

```
    BufferedReader input;

    if(stream != null){
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                stream));
    String responseLine = "";
    String server_response = "";
    try {
        while (((responseLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
             server_response = server_response + responseLine  + "\r\n";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    server_response = server_response + "\r\n.\r\n";
  }
```

am I miss something? or that what you asked for?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I put the InputStream inside a while loop to read all the input lines till the end, you think he wanna to identify the line with `"\r\n.\r\n"` ? what I understood is that he want to add it at the end of the input, as he said "at the end I want to add"

Comment: In fact I don't know, may be you are right and may be I'm right, I think he has to illustrate a little bit more